# Multiple virtual hosts with different env files in docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, environment-variables, virtualhost

I'm using docker-compose and I've a dev server with lot of virtual hosts on Nginx+PHP-FPM. At the moment nginx container handles multiple virtual hosts:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx:1.17.4-alpine
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    labels:
      - 'com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true'
    restart: always
  dockergen:
    [...]
  letsencrypt:
    [...]
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17.4-alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: proj1.site.com, proj2.example.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: proj1.site.com, proj2.example.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: tech@example.com
    volumes:
      - './proj1:/proj1'
      - './proj2:/proj2'
      - './site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf'
  php:
    build:
      context: ./php
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - './proj1:/proj1'
      - './proj2:/proj2'
    restart: always

volumes:
  conf:
  vhost:
  html:
  certs:
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Now, I'd like to separate the virtual host containers, because I need to inject different env files. Should i replicate the nginx container (of course with different name) and the site.conf per each project? Am I doing it the right way? Could you please suggest me the right direction? P.S. I've read that extends keyword is deprecated for docker-compose v3, so I'd like to avoid that if possible.